# Dynamic width in React returns 'false' value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, width

I wanted to make my image responsive, therefore I used a custom hook called `useWindowSize`
now I'm in 320px width but my condition doesn't applies and returns an error.
to clarify the problem these are my hook,`img` tag and error:

`useWindowSize` :

```
import React from "react";

export default function useWindowSize() {
  const isSSR = typeof window !== "undefined";
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = React.useState({
    width: isSSR ? 1200 : window.innerWidth,
    height: isSSR ? 800 : window.innerHeight,
  });

  function changeWindowSize() {
    setWindowSize({ width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight });
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", changeWindowSize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", changeWindowSize);
    };
  }, []);

  return windowSize;
}
```

`img` tag:

```
  <img
    src={AIRobot}
    alt="AI_Robot"
    width={Width < 768 && "60%"}
    height="60%"
  />
```

error :
[image]

Comment: Try `width={Width < 768 ? "60%" : undefined}`

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation) behavior of logical and operator `&&`.

Examples:

```js
a6 = false && 'Cat'      // f && t returns false
```

The error message is clear since the `width` props is a non-boolean data type. You can't pass a boolean value to it.

If you don't want to set value for `width` props when `width >= 768`, you can use the default value of CSS width - `'auto'`

```
<img width={width < 768 ? '60%' : 'auto'}/>
```